# Condition_variable C++

Tags: c++

There is a simple example of using Condition_variable:

```
#include <iostream>           // std::cout
#include <thread>             // std::thread
#include <mutex>              // std::mutex, std::unique_lock
#include <condition_variable> // std::condition_variable



std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cv;
int global_status = 0;

void print_id(int id) 
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);


    while (global_status == 0)
    {
        cv.wait(lck);
    }


    std::cout << "thread " << id << '\n';
}


int main()
{
    std::thread threads[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        threads[i] = std::thread(print_id, i);
    }
  


    std::cout << "Start" << std::endl;


    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));            

{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
    global_status = 1;
    cv.notify_all();
}

    for (auto& th : threads) th.join();

    return 0;
}
```

I still can't figure out why block the global_status variable when I change its value?
I change the value global_status from only one thread - why then they block it mutex ? Or is it not necessary?

Comment: never wait without a predicate, I also seem to be missing a cv.notify_all(). Also read this if you're going to work with condition variables! 
https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guidelines-be-aware-of-the-traps-of-condition-variables

Comment: You are missing the whole notion of condition_variable here. while() {wait} is a busy wait situation, and this is exactly what you want to avoid in by using condition_variable. You have there a while loop that does no processing. Just put the global_status in a the cv.wait lambda function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I change the value global_status from only one thread - why then they block it mutex

You need the mutex because you read the value in different threads.